# How to execute save operation immediatly in a @Transactional method

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data

Say I have following code snippet

```
@Transactional
public void doSthing(){
     // save an enetity to db
    SomeClass entityA = new entityA();
    mapper.save(entityA);
    // I got null here!
    Integer id = entityA.getId();
    anotherEntity.setVal(id);
    otherMapper.upate(anotherEntity)

}
```

as u see, I need the entityA's id to update another entity, but it's `null` at that time, if I remove the `@Transactional` it works, but I want the two operations in tansaction, which mean that i need spring rollback the `doSthing()` method on any opereation failured.

Comment: So you want to rollback everything in case of exceptions?

Comment: When calling save and you have a generated ID that should be immediate. If not there is something weird with your code (what does that mapper do/look like)?

Comment: @NiVeR yes ,rollback everythig on any excepton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, methods annotated with `@Transactional` will rollback on any `RuntimeException`. So you can achieve the rollback by throwing some runtime exception under some condition.

If you want to rollback on **any** exception just add the following:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
```

But what @Delinum said in the comment is true in general, that is, if you invoke a save on a dao/repository it should assign an `@Id` to the value object that you are saving, making it an entity.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is type of your 'mapper' instance, but some implementations could work in a way that when you call save it doesn't change the original object, but rather it returns the persisted object. So instead of this:

```
mapper.save(entityA);
// I got null here!
Integer id = entityA.getId();
```

Use this:

```
Integer id = mapper.save(entityA).getId();
```